# Angular 5 build modules failure

Tags: angular, typescript, deployment, mean-stack

I have an angular app decomposed into 5 modules when I try to build the app using `ng build --prod`
I receive an error message for each module like this one

[Angular Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6KLqM.png)

> ERROR in ./src/app/Modules/profile/profile.module.ts Module build
>   failed: Error:
>   /Users/amrmkayid/Desktop/Nawwar-Heroku/angular-src/src/app/Modules/profile/profile.module.ts
>   is missing from the TypeScript compilation. Please make sure it is in
>   your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property.
>       at AngularCompilerPlugin.getCompiledFile (/Users/amrmkayid/Desktop/Nawwar-Heroku/angular-src/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/angular_compiler_plugin.js:662:23)
>       at plugin.done.then (/Users/amrmkayid/Desktop/Nawwar-Heroku/angular-src/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/loader.js:467:39)
>       at 
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:160:7)  @ ./src/$$_lazy_route_resource lazy  @
>   ./node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js  @ ./src/main.ts  @ multi
>   ./src/main.ts

how can I solve this problem?!

Comment: check with this [link](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9523)..